# FreeIPA and AD password synchronisation

Tags: linux, active-directory, single-sign-on, freeipa, 389-ds

I am attempting to integrate FreeIPA with Active Directory to provide single-sign-on for Windows and Linux users by following [this guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/active-directory.html).

I have successfully created the 'winsync' agreement and loaded the AD data into FreeIPA but I am struggling to setup the Windows Password Synchronization from [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/FreeIPA_Guide/pass-sync.html) part of the guide.

When a user changes their password, I see the following in the 389 PassSync plugin log on the Domain Controller:

```
06/17/16 08:47:32: Backoff time expired.  Attempting sync
06/17/16 08:47:32: Password list has 1 entries
06/17/16 08:47:32: Attempting to sync password for some.user
06/17/16 08:47:32: Searching for (ntuserdomainid=some.user)
06/17/16 08:47:32: Ldap error in QueryUsername
34: Invalid DN syntax
06/17/16 08:47:32: Deferring password change for some.user
06/17/16 08:47:32: Backing off for 1024000ms
```

When I run the query from the CLI, using the same user and password used by the PassSync plugin, it is successful:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h ldaps://localhost -p 636 -D 'uid=passsync,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=dc,my=domain,dc=com' -w 'password'  -b 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com' '(ntuserdomainid=some.user)'
```

Can anyone point out what I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like you did not actually share the part of your configuration that had the problem. That could be why nobody else was able to answer. I'm also not sure if it will be useful to anyone else without that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, I'll post my findings to help anyone else that has a similar issue.

On the IPA server, I found the 389-ds log: `/var/log/dirsrv/slapd-HOSTNAME/access`

Looking at the entries in the log I noticed some extra characters in the DN that corresponds to "Search Base".  I got the Windows admin to share his RDP session to the DC and had a look at the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PasswordSync`.

Here I noticed the same characters in the "Search Base" key.  I think these extra characters were accidentally copy-pasted from the documentation.

Removing them and restarting the service has resolved the problem.